# Maven <activeByDefault> tag strange behaviour

Tags: maven, build

Here is my settings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>wiki</id>
      <properties>
        <repo.url>wikipedia.pl</repo.url>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>youtube</id>
      <properties>
        <repo.url>youtube.pl</repo.url>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

</settings>
```

And pom.xml with echo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>Repository url: </echo>
                                <echo>${repo.url}</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

When i run **mvn package** I assume that profile **youtube** will be activated (and it is = in logs shows *youtube.pl*). But when I type **mvn -P wiki package** it should be *wikipedia.pl* in logs but it is still *youtube.pl* - why? Is it problem with **activeByDefault** tag?

When profiles are in pom.xml there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the introduction docs https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html explain this. although easy to overlook. Profiles in the settings.xml that you activate by default are enabled for all builds.

Profiles in you pom that are enabled by default are disabled if you enable a different one:

> This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the previously described methods.

and regarding the settings.xml profiles:

> This option takes an argument that is a comma-delimited list of profile-ids to use. When this option is specified, the profile(s) specified in the option argument will be activated in addition to any profiles which are activated by their activation configuration or the  section in settings.xml.

It seems you want to change an url for uploading depending on a profile. I would argue this falls under the "portable builds" recommendation. Anyone that does not share the settings.xml will not be able to repeat what the build is doing.

If you want to "hide" these url's from the builds to only have them available on a CI server you could set different properties in the same settings.xml profile, and use two profiles in your pom that will set the uri from one of the values.

Another solution for you may be to just disable a profile with the -P!profileId option.